# Using multiple custom post types (Bones Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've made a custom content-type for my Bones Theme but when I try to add another custom content type my site stops working and only displays a blank page.

I think it has something to do with the require_once or the function name.

This is my function.php

```
require_once( 'library/team.php' );
require_once( 'library/partners.php' );
```

And this in my custom post PHP files.

```
function custom_post_team()
function custom_post_partners()
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Added the php from the the files.

Postype: "partners"

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'bones_flush_rewrite_rules' );


function bones_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function custom_post_partners() { 

    register_post_type( 'partners', 

        array( 'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Partners', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'singular_name' => __( 'Partners', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'all_items' => __( 'Partners', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Partner', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post Types', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'new_item' => __( 'New Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'view_item' => __( 'View Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Post Type', 'bonestheme' ),
            'not_found' =>  __( 'Nothing found in the Database.', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
            ), 
            'description' => __( 'Partners', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 8, 
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png', 
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'partners', 'with_front' => false ), 
            'has_archive' => false, 
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,

            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'sticky')
        ) 
    ); 

}
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_partners');    

?>
```

Posttype: team

```
<?php

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'bones_flush_rewrite_rules' );

function bones_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function custom_post_team() { 

    register_post_type( 'team', 

        array( 'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Team', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'singular_name' => __( 'Team', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'all_items' => __( 'Team', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Team Member', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post Types', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'new_item' => __( 'New Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'view_item' => __( 'View Post Type', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Post Type', 'bonestheme' ),
            'not_found' =>  __( 'Nothing found in the Database.', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
            ), 
            'description' => __( 'Team', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 8, 
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/custom-post-icon.png', 
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'team', 'with_front' => false ), 
            'has_archive' => false, 
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,

            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'sticky')
        ) 
    ); 

}

    add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_team');

?>
```

Functions.php

```
<?php

require_once( 'library/bones.php' );

function bones_ahoy() {

  add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/editor-style.css' );

  load_theme_textdomain( 'bonestheme', get_template_directory() . '/library/translation' );

    require_once( 'library/team.php' );
    require_once( 'library/partners.php' );

  add_action( 'init', 'bones_head_cleanup' );
  add_filter( 'wp_title', 'rw_title', 10, 3 );
  add_filter( 'the_generator', 'bones_rss_version' );
  add_filter( 'wp_head', 'bones_remove_wp_widget_recent_comments_style', 1 );
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'bones_remove_recent_comments_style', 1 );
  add_filter( 'gallery_style', 'bones_gallery_style' );

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bones_scripts_and_styles', 999 );

  bones_theme_support();

  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'bones_register_sidebars' );

  add_filter( 'the_content', 'bones_filter_ptags_on_images' );
  add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'bones_excerpt_more' );

} 

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bones_ahoy' );


if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 640;
}

add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-600', 600, 150, true );
add_image_size( 'bones-thumb-300', 300, 100, true );
add_image_size( 'news-thumb-290', 290, 190, true );
add_image_size( 'news-thumb-140', 140, 84, true );

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'bones_custom_image_sizes' );

function bones_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'bones-thumb-600' => __('600px by 150px'),
        'bones-thumb-300' => __('300px by 100px'),
        'news-thumb-290' => __('290px by 190px'),
        'news-thumb-140' => __('140px by 84px'),
    ) );
}

function bones_theme_customizer($wp_customize) {
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'bones_theme_customizer' );


function arphabet_widgets_init() {

  register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Footer',
    'id'            => 'footer-area',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<div class="marquee-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</div>',
  ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );

function bones_register_sidebars() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => 'sidebar1',
        'name' => __( 'Sidebar 1', 'bonestheme' ),
        'description' => __( 'The first (primary) sidebar.', 'bonestheme' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));

} 


function bones_comments( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
  <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class('cf'); ?>>
    <article  class="cf">
      <header class="comment-author vcard">
        <?php

        ?>
        <?php  ?>
        <?php

          $bgauthemail = get_comment_author_email();
        ?>
        <img data-gravatar="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<?php echo md5( $bgauthemail ); ?>?s=40" class="load-gravatar avatar avatar-48 photo" height="40" width="40" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/nothing.gif" />
        <?php ?>
        <?php printf(__( '<cite class="fn">%1$s</cite> %2$s', 'bonestheme' ), get_comment_author_link(), edit_comment_link(__( '(Edit)', 'bonestheme' ),'  ','') ) ?>
        <time datetime="<?php echo comment_time('Y-m-j'); ?>"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php comment_time(__( 'F jS, Y', 'bonestheme' )); ?> </a></time>

      </header>
      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
          <p><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'bonestheme' ) ?></p>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <section class="comment_content cf">
        <?php comment_text() ?>
      </section>
      <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
    </article>
  <?php ?>
<?php
} 


function bones_fonts() {
  wp_enqueue_style('googleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bones_fonts');

    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'comment-list',
        'search-form',
        'comment-form'
    ) );

?>
```

Comment: please show your calls to `register_post_type()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you already tried, what errors you get (if any) and so on. Further we need at least the mentioned parts of code to help.

Comment: Minor formatting and typo correction. You'll get better answers if you can provide some error log information of more detail. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post. Hope it's more clear right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem by combining the different post types into one file instead of in seperate files. Works now.